# XamDataGrid support for ITypedList

Tags: wpf, infragistics

In both cases the docs just mention that any `IEnumerable` will do. I have a custom object that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `ITypedList` and I am bindind it to `XamGrid.ItemSource` and it works. However, it doesn't work with `XamDataGrid.DataSource`. I want the grid to reflect the changes to the custom collection.

I know about the solution with `DataSet` adapter. Are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XamDataGrid has logic for ITypedLIst so if that isn't working you should let Infragistics know by contacting [support](http://www.infragistics.com/help/) and providing an example.

If the changes to the collection aren't being reflected in the grid, make sure that the collection the grid is using implements change notifications such as an ObservableCollection.

If the changes to the data items aren't being updated correctly then you should make sure that the object in the list is raising change notifications through the INotifyPropertyChanged interface when you expect the changes to happen.

If you have already verified that your collection does correctly implement change notifications and that the objects also raise change notifications, then you should contact [Infragistics support](http://www.infragistics.com/help/) with an example so they can look into it.

Comment: It turned out that I got the question wrong since I wanted to provide ITypedList as a datasource. ITypedList seems to be working for XamGrid but it does not for XamDataGrid. Instead, I went for a solution with DataSet adapter. Thank you for your answer, anyway.

Comment: I checked and there is logic for ITypedList so I would still recommend contacting Infragistics support with an example if ITypedList doesn't work as you expect.  I have also updated my answer to reference ITypedList rather than IListSource.